# Send email from localhost to Gmail

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am new to PHP & want to we send email from localhost to my gmail address.

I am using ubuntu 9.10 & have already installed libphp-phpmailer from Synaptic Package manager option.

I used:

```
$to      = "abc@gmail.com";
$subject = "Account Confirmation";
$headers = "From: xyz@gmail.com";
$message = "Testing";
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if ($mail) {
    echo "Mail sent.";
} else {
   echo "Some Error occur.";
}
```

And it show Some Error occur.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sendmail services
to intall

apt-get install sendmail

It makes your computer to be mail server and you can send wherever you want with domain that you want...

Comment: I used it & it just show "Mail sent" but when i login from abc@gmail.com then there was no email at all.

Comment: Check Spam folder and change From: adb@domain.com

Comment: You'll also need to set sendmail to send mails.. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=196112

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SO.

assume under "localhost" you mean "windows".
you will need either to install your own mail server or to use some SMTP class, like `PHPMailer`, to send mail using your IPS's server

Comment: Can you not read that the question specifies the user is on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Felix yes I can not read the text before it was added to question.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need PHPMailer (thus the `libphp-phpmailer` package) to use the `mail()` function (also, I would recommend [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) over PHPMailer anytime). Also, if you want to use the `mail()` function you will need a Mail Transport Agent (**MTA**). I recommend installing the `postfix` package (it's available by default in Ubuntu, just use `sudo apt-get install postfix`). After that, your code should output `Mail sent.` :)

-1 to the other two answers for not reading your question.